# How to script an Azure repository search using az cli

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm fairly new to Azure cli. I've got a case where I'd like to perform a search on each of my code repos in Azure devops and check for the version of a dependency in the pom.xml file.

The front end search via the web console provides something very close to what i need but i can't easily export the results. In the front end I enter in a search like so and it kind of gives me what i need.

[image]

Whats the best way to replicate this behaviour to produce a kind of report using the azure cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In az cli, there is [az repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos?view=azure-cli-latest) to manage Azure Repos. You could run `az repos show` to get the details of a Git repository, but there is no Code search commands.

Instead of az cli, you could use [Code Search Results - Fetch Code Search Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/code%20search%20results/fetch%20code%20search%20results?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST api in your script to get results of the search text.

```
POST https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

The script uses the api looks like:

```
Param( 
[string]$organisation = "org", 
[string]$project = "projectname", 
[string]$keepForever = "true", 
[string]$user = " ", 
[string]$token = "PAT" ) 

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$postresults = "https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/$organisation/$project/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=6.0-preview.1" 

 $body = '{

}'

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $postresults -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've got it to work. Works like a treat although there is a bug in the rest api which stops me from getting the results i'm after (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/465?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container). That's not something we can address in this thread.